# How do I compile and install USBguard on android?

Tags: security, usb, linux

Is it even possible to compile and install linux packages on android, if it is possible how do I install usbguard into android?

Comment: you can run static command line binaries from linux arm/aarch64 packages but no linux software, except you are running linux on top of android (linux deploy)

Comment: You should better ask such question on the [USBguard mailing list](https://usbguard.github.io/community.html). There they know better what requirements (kernel and other) have to be present for USBguard to run. As it requires a special service intergrating USBguard at least require root permissions on android plus various system modifications. Or directly develop a matching customROM with integrated USBguard.

Comment: As Robert said it won't simply work on Android since it relies on components like `systemd`, D-Bus based IPC and `polkit`, which are specific to Linux distros, not available on Android.